# The Greenhouse Problem version 2

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

This is an extension of Nilster's great puzzle: [The Greenhouse Problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107029/the-greenhouse-problem)

The task is the same, but this time sprinklers cover only a **3x3** square around them. For completeness, here is the full set of rules:

- The greenhouse floor is made of tiles arranged in a 9x11 rectangle. The door is on the center of the 11-length edge.
- Each plant takes up 1 tile.
- Each plant needs to be watered by a sprinkler. Each sprinkler waters a **3x3** square around it.
- A plant and a sprinkler cannot be placed on the same tile.
- I must be able to reach every plant orthogonally. I cannot walk on plants or sprinklers. I can only move orthogonally.
- Asymmetry is allowed. The fewer sprinklers, the better, but there's no limit.

What is the most number plants possible in this greenhouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a symmetric solution with

> 50 plants:

> \begin{matrix} &S &P &P &S &P &. &P &S &P &P &S\\ &P &. &. &P &P &. &P &P &. &. &P\\ &P &. &P &S &P &. &P &S &P &. &P\\ &S &. &P &P &P &. &P &P &P &. &S\\ &P &. &. &. &. &. &. &. &. &. &P\\ &S &. &P &P &P &. &P &P &P &. &S\\ &P &. &P &S &P &. &P &S &P &. &P\\ &P &. &. &P &P &. &P &P & . &. &P\\ &S &P &P &S &P &. &P &S &P &P &S\\\end{matrix}

Comment: Excellent work Rob!

Answer (score 2):

I could place

> **49 plants**

in this way (which is also more symmetric than the previous one):

> ```
> S P . P S P S P . P S
> P P . P P . P P . P P
> . . . P P . P P . . .
> P P . P S . S P . P P
> S P . P P . P P . P S
> P P . . . . . . . P P
> . . . P P . P P . . .
> P P . P S . S P . P P
> S P . P P . P P . P S
> ```

Another one with the same count:

> ```
> S P . P S . S P . P S
> P P . P P P P P . P P
> . . . . . . . . . . .
> P P . P S P P P . P P
> S P . P P P S P . P S
> P P . . . . P P . P P
> . . . P P P S P . . .
> P P . P S P P P . P P
> S P . P P . . . . P S
> ```

Comment: This is a great start!

Comment: I tried various other patterns and non-patterns, but tweaking them all converged to the existing ones. I'm suspecting the current number is optimal.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not optimal. Better solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Same P-count as @Bubbler but I managed to squeeze out one S:

> ```
>  
>     P S P . P S P . P S P
>     . P P . P P P . P P .
>     . . . . . . . . . . .
>     P P P P P . P P P P P
>     S . P S P . P S P . S
>     P . P P P . P P P . P
>     P . . . . . . . . . P
>     S . P P P . P P P . S
>     P . P S P . P S P . P
> ```

Answer (score 1):

My solver found some more solutions with the optimal number of plants:

> 50 plants
>
> ```
>  S P P S P P S P P S P
>  P . . . . . . . . . .
>  P . P P P P P P . P P
>  S . P S P P S P . P S
>  P . P P . . P P . P P
>  S . P S P . P P . . .
>  P . P P P . P S P P P
>  P . . . . . P P P P S
>  S P P S P . . . . . P
>
> and
>
>  S P . P S P P S P P S
>  P P . P P . . . . . P
>  . . . P S P P P P . P
>  P P . P P P P S P . S
>  S P . . . . . P P . P
>  P P . P P P P S P . P
>  . . . P S P P P P . S
>  P P . P P . . . . . P
>  S P . . . . P S P P S
> ```